# Google Sheets - formula =A1:A2:A3 is valid, but what does it do?

Tags: google-sheets

I can see that it appears to copy the range A1:A3 to the cell where I put the formula and the cells to the right, but why? I cannot find this syntax in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

while it works, it's not meant to be used for obvious reasons - lenght

```
=A1:A2:A3:A4:A5:A6:A7:A8:A9
```

vs.

```
={A1:A9}
```

vs.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A9)
```

vs.

```
=INDEX(A1:A9)
```

vs.

```
=QUERY(A1:A9)
```

Comment: These appear to not be equivalent. "=A1:A7" gives a value error, while "=A1:A2:A3:A4:A5:A6:A7" copies the range.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando answer updated

Comment: So it just creates an array?

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando yes. nothing more than just a simple array